# Pandas - create a heading row by merging cells (agg group?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with my raw  dataset to report and have almost come to the "final format" that I need. At the moment, I am at this dataframe with product sales (qty, and subtotal) from each customer group (wholesale, Retail, Other)

| SKU | Product Name | Qty_Wholesale | Subtotal_Wholesale | Qty_Retail | Subtotal_Retail | Qty_Other | Subtotal_Other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU123 | Red Wine - Cabernet Sauvignon | 0 | 0 | 5 | 129.95 | 0 | 0 |
| SKU234 | Ros Wine - Pinot Noir | 4 | 79.96 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 19.99 |
| SKU890 | White Wine - Sauvignon Blanc | 0 | 0 | 1 | 27.99 | 0 | 0 |

The final format requires 1 additional heading row representing the customer group  (please disregard the bolding/format as I couldn't figure out the best way to format the table on stackoverflow) . As per table below,  I'm trying  to  figure out how to merge column 3+ 4 into 1 and label it Wholesale,  then do the same for 5+6 and 7+8..

|  |  | Wholesale |  | Retail |  | Other |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SKU | Product Name | Qty | Subtotal | Qty | Subtotal | Qty | Subtotal |
| SKU123 | Red Wine - Cabernet Sauvignon | 0 | 0 | 5 | 129.95 | 0 | 0 |
| SKU234 | Ros Wine - Pinot Noir | 4 | 79.96 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 19.99 |
| SKU890 | White Wine - Sauvignon Blanc | 0 | 0 | 1 | 27.99 | 0 | 0 |

I've been going in circles with this. Could some one please help a fellow out

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

don make row & use multi index

```
tmp = df.set_index(['SKU', 'Product Name'])
out = tmp.set_axis(tmp.columns.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split('_')[::-1])), axis=1)
```

out:

[image]

---

If you want to use a 1-line code, use the following code.

```
df.set_index(['SKU', 'Product Name'])\
  .set_axis(df.columns[2:].map(lambda x: tuple(x.split('_')[::-1])), axis=1)
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'SKU': ['SKU123', 'SKU234', 'SKU890'],
 'Product Name': ['Red Wine - Cabernet Sauvignon',
  'Ros Wine - Pinot Noir',
  'White Wine - Sauvignon Blanc'],
 'Qty_Wholesale': [0, 4, 0],
 'Subtotal_Wholesale': [0.0, 79.96, 0.0],
 'Qty_Retail': [5, 0, 1],
 'Subtotal_Retail': [129.95, 0.0, 27.99],
 'Qty_Other': [0, 4, 0],
 'Subtotal_Other': [0.0, 19.99, 0.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Split and expand the columns to convert into multiindex

```
df1 = df.set_index(['SKU', 'Product Name'])
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True).swaplevel()
```

---

```
print(df1)
                                              Wholesale          Retail          Other         
                                           Qty Subtotal    Qty Subtotal   Qty Subtotal
SKU    Product Name                                                                   
SKU123 Red Wine - Cabernet Sauvignon         0     0.00      5   129.95     0     0.00
SKU234 Ros Wine - Pinot Noir                 4    79.96      0     0.00     4    19.99
SKU890 White Wine - Sauvignon Blanc          0     0.00      1    27.99     0     0.00
```

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know about this multiindex thing until now